# No funciona MsgBoxStyle en la aplicación web

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy utilizando `MsgBoxStyle` en el controlador de mi aplicación web en *Visual Basic*, todo funciona bien en la máquina local pero cuando la paso a internet deja de funcionar.

```
Dim TipoMensaje = MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 Or MsgBoxStyle.Question
Dim response = MsgBox("Desea Modificar el Registro", TipoMensaje, "Confirmacion de Modificación")
```

Comment: La bola de cirstal se nos rompió el otro día, lo siento. Ya en serio, bienvenido a StackOverflow. Aunque pueda parecer obvio no somos adivinos, si quieres que te ayudemos tienes que presentar un ejemplo mínimo que permita reproducir el problema. Con lo poco que comentas poco podemos hacer aparte de darte el pésame.

Comment: Hola hola, disculpa eferion voy a ponerte una fracción del código

Comment: No hablo solo de mí sino de la comunidad en general. Si no aportas la información necesaria es imposible ayudarte

Comment: Si en algo te ayuda, puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Con gusto te apoyaremos.

Comment: Dim TipoMensaje = MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 Or MsgBoxStyle.Question
                    Dim response = MsgBox("Desea Modificar el Registro", TipoMensaje, "Confirmacion de Modificación"), Este es el código, funciona bien localmente, pero en el momento que se publica, tira un error y según lo que leí este msgbox no funciona en web, quería saber si sabian de alguna alternativa, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código como parte de tu pregunta? Pulsa el enlace que pone "editar" y posteriormente, tras pegar el código, selecciónalo y luego pulsa el icono de las llaves `{}`.

Comment: {Dim TipoMensaje = MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 Or MsgBoxStyle.Question Dim response = MsgBox("Desea Modificar el Registro", TipoMensaje, "Confirmacion de Modificación"),} Este es el código, funciona bien localmente, pero en el momento que se publica, tira un error y según lo que leí este msgbox no funciona en web, quería saber si sabian de alguna alternativa, muchas gracias.

Comment: A lo que nos referimos es que edites tu pregunta inicial, y pongas fragmento de tu código. Sin embargo veo que estas programando en asp. El procedimiento para programar los botones y mensajes cambian, te invito a que investigues un poco más de [Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp) y [ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6w2tb12s(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: La respuesta a tu problema es que el objeto MessageBox que utilizas programando en VB no forma parte del resultado que pueden ver los clientes (la página). Eso significa que ese tipo de código solo es ejecutado del lado servidor y no del lado cliente. Para abrir un "messagebox" o mejor dicho un "alert" es necesario que lo programes en JavaScript, como dijo @cport93

Comment: Que tal Mauricio, como menciona @Agustin M. es una aplicación web la cual los MessageBox no son visibles ya que es un método que sólo te funcionará en aplicaciones winforms (Aplicaciones de escritorio), en ese caso se puede hacer uso de JavaScript para mostrar alertas que son similares a los MessageBox.

Te dejo una liga donde se ve un ejemplo: http://ltuttini.blogspot.mx/2010/04/aspnet-javascript-alert-y-confirm-como.html

Comment: Muchisimas gracias a todos, es de gran ayuda la información que me brindaron